# How to understand $\partial^2F(x, y) \over \partial x \partial y $ = $f(x, y)$

Tags: probability-distributions

$\partial^2F(x, y) \over \partial x \partial y $ = $f(x, y)$  --------------- (1)
This formula comes to me but I have no idea what it means. Especially what the $\partial^2$ and $\partial x$ represent.

Do this one has the exact meaning as below one which I understand?

$P\{(X, Y) \in D$} = $\iint_D f(x, y) dxdy$  --------------- (2)

Taking an example, if $F(x, y) = {1 \over \pi^2}({\pi \over 2} + arctan x)({\pi \over 2} + arctan 2y) $,
how to use (1) to get the $f(x, y)$ ?

Comment: It's the mixed partial deriviative of $F$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$. So differentiate your function with repsect to $x$ holding $y$ constant, then differentiate with respect to $y$ holiding $x$ constant.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\Phi'(x)$ for $\Phi: x\mapsto f(x,\cdot)$, and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\Psi'(y)$ for $\Psi: y\mapsto f(\cdot ,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says that the function $F(x,y)$ of two variables has the second order partial derivative
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} F(x,y) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x,y)\right) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x,y) = 
F_{xy}(x,y) = f(x,y)
$$

This is different from your equation $(2)$.

The partial derivatives can be defined like this
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,y) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x+h, y) - F(x,y)}{h} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} F(x,y) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x, y+h) - F(x,y)}{h}
$$

If $F$ is given the calculation of $f$ is easy, the partial derivative regarding $x$ can be calculated by assuming $y$ constant and applying the one dimensional derivation for $x$. (And vice versa for $y$, treating $x$ as a constant).

If $f$ is given, but $F$ not, then you have a second order partial differential equation. The solution will involve two integrations.

For your example
$$
F(x, y) = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan x\right)
\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan 2y\right) 
$$
one gets
$$
F_y(x, y) 
= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan x\right)
\left(0 + (\arctan 2y)'\right) 
= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan x\right)
\left(\frac{2}{1+(2y)^2}\right) 
$$
and
$$
F_{xy}(x, y) 
= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F_y 
= 
\frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(0 + (\arctan x)'\right)
\left(\frac{2}{1+(2y)^2}\right) 
= 
\frac{1}{\pi^2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)
\left(\frac{2}{1+(2y)^2}\right) 
$$

Comment: Is $(\arctan f(x))' = {f'(x) \over 1+f^2(x)}$?

Comment: Yes, by the chain rule. $h(f(x))' = h'(f(x)) f'(x)$